# Is there any code regarding in-wall convection ovens?

Tags: code-compliance, oven

Are there any code restrictions involving in-wall convection ovens?

Comment: Gas or electric? Both will need to be installed according to mfg instructions, gas will require a vent.

Answer (score 1):

A stand alone appliance will always come under Underwriters Laboratories jurisdiction.  The manufacturer's install instruction will dictate proper guidelines. If a local inspector is involved he can and sometimes does ask for this literature and check things out.  Involving a convection oven, I would rigidly follow these instructions and even might error on the side of caution.

Comment: U.L. doesn't have a "jurisdiction", manufacturers choose to pay for their testing and certification services (or not). U.L. listing/certification is not required unless the applicable code says it is (granted, for appliances in the US this would likely be the case, but this site is global).

Answer (score 0):

The code that applies depends on where you live. In California, it is the Cal Mechanical Code (CCR, Title 24, Part 4), which often incorporates other codes (plumbing, electrical, etc.) and standards (NFPA, etc.) by reference. Your local code enforcement authority may also have requirements specific to your locale (also a great place to inquire as to what codes apply in your area/region).